# IronPython and ASP.NET: ready for prime time?

Tags: asp.net, ironpython

Has anyone actually built and deployed a website with IronPython and ASP.NET. What were your experiences and is the combination ready for prime-time?

I asked this question just over a year ago. And the consensus seemed to be "not really".

What's the status now?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually ever tried it, however I do know there's a library available which allows you to write inline python in your ASP.NET.

It would seem to me that this is very usable in a production scenario.

[Gestalt](http://www.visitmix.com/labs/gestalt/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you want to do anthing useful/em> with .NET + IronPython, you need better support for the dynamicy of Microsoft's CLR environment, and you'll need VS2010 for that.

You may have better luck just building a strait up python app. Why bother using ASP.NET? Are you integrating with another codebase?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that ASP.NET was ever ready for prime time. The framework is contrived and an awful fit for designing web applications. It was made for VB6 programmers that only know how to drag controls onto a design surface.

Most decent(and pretty much all bad) applications written on ASP.NET don't use it as it was designed, and if that's the case then what's the point.

Comment: You do know that stackoverflow was written with ASP.NET, don't you?

Comment: lol, no it wasn't, it was written in ASP.NET MVC which is totally different.